# Objective C - UIBezierPath is not stroking path properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I am trying to create a circle using Core Graphics that is being filled and a stroke is given to it here is the code that is inside drawRect method

```
    [color setFill];
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setStroke];

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect];

    path.lineWidth = 1;
    [path fill];
    [path stroke];
```

I am creating this view inside another view of same size. I am experiencing a strange behavior. I am getting the output something like that

[image]

What i am doing wrong or what i have to add to make the drawing right. I have set the `[circleView setClipsToBounds:NO];` but same result.

Comment: frame size issue may be. Please provide full code of `drawRect:`

Comment: you can increase the canvas size a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happened because you draw circle with rectangle with the line with of 1 which draws half of the line off the frame. Try to inset the rectangle:

```
CGRect r = CGRectInset(rect, 1, 1);
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:r];
```